# How to use negation in npm script glob pattern?

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-scripts

I am trying to create a `clean` npm script but I continue to either get an error in the console or the desired effect does not happen. I am trying to delete all of the root JavaScript files except some config files.

The following removes all of the files ignoring the negate syntax

```
"clean": "rm -rf lib [a-z].js !*.config.js !*.support.js"
```

The following throws an error in the console

```
"clean": "rm -rf lib !(*.config|*.support).js"
```

```
Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Comment: are you trying to call the unix command `rm` using regex patterns? Does that actually work?

Comment: Note that the command you are trying to run may be shell-specific (bash, zsh, ksh, etc), so you may want to look into using the [`rimraf`](https://github.com/isaacs/rimraf) module

Comment: I've got it working fine when not using negation.  I can specify specific files and folders I want to remove, but when I try to do all root js except the config files I am running into issues.

Comment: @smac89 I ran into the same problem when using `rimraf` so I switched back to `rm`

Comment: I think your globs are contradictory: 1) remove lib 2) anything single lowercase letter js file. 3) anything that's not a .config.js or .support.js file. Using `()` doesn't work in bash. What shell are you running?

Comment: @smac89 - [Ranges](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#Ranges) such as `[a-z]`, are supported in some glob implementations. The 1st example in the OP actually works for me, both running direct via the CLi and via the npm script. However, the _extended glob_ pattern in the OP's 2nd example works direct via the CLI (with `shopt -s extglob` i.e. with _extglob_ set to on) but fails via a npm script. I think you're right to suggest `rimraf` for portability/cross-platform goodness. Using `rimraf` with _extended glob_ patterns in the npm script does need to be wrapped in `\"...\"` as per my answer tho.

Comment: I am using bash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilize [rimraf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf) and wrap the complex glob pattern(s) in JSON escaped double quotes, i.e. `\"...\"`

For instance:

```json
"clean": "rimraf lib \"!(*.config|*.support).js\""
```

This example (above)

1. Deletes the `lib` directory from the root of the project directory.
2. Deletes all `.js` files from the root of the project directory. However, files ending `.config.js` or `.support.js` (such as `foobar.config.js` and `quux.support.js`) will be negated.

**Edit:** Using the following bash [find](https://ss64.com/bash/find.html) command via a npm script also achieves the desired result:

```json
"clean": "find . \\( -name '*.js' -o -name 'lib' \\) -not \\( -name '*.config.js' -o -name '*.support.js' \\) -maxdepth 1 -exec rm -rf {} \\;"
```

However I'd opt for the aforementioned `rimraf` approach for greater portability across platforms, including Windows `cmd.exe`

Comment: I think the reason why the `rm -rf` cmds in your OP don't run successfully via npm scripts is because npm uses `sh` and not `bash` to execute the scripts (`sh` doesn't support extended globs). Since npm  _v5.1_ it introduced the [script-shell](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#script-shell) option. So, (if the `rm -rf` commands actually run successfully direct via your CLI) you could try: **1)** Run `which bash` and it will return the path,  e.g. `/bin/bash`. **2)** Run `npm config set script-shell "/bin/bash"` to set the shell to use. **3)** Then try running your original npm scripts  again.